# How to do Nextjs dynamic routing?

Tags: dynamic, routes, next.js

How to do Nextjs dynamic routing?

I've code like this already, this works, however if you refresh the page, you will get 404 page

```
<Link
     href={`/categorypage?c1=${data.categoria}&c2=${data2.categoria}`} 
          as={`${data.categoria}/${data2.categoria}`}> 
            <a>{data2.categorianame}</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Routes like this:
like this
http://emample-site.com/nike/sneakers
http://emample-site.com/adidas/sneakers
http://emample-site.com/puma/hoodies
instead of this
http://emample-site.com/category/puma/hoodies

Comment: Can you show us your `pages` folder structure?